# Adding Keys in CountingBloomFilter Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, key, typeconverter

I am trying to use the implementation of the CountingBloomFilter proposed by Hadoop.
After importing the libraries and creating the classe, I want to use this method

```
add(org.apache.hadoop.util.bloom.Key key)
```

However I need to add strings to my filter, how can I convert my string to a key that this function could accept?

Answer (score 0):

Key has a constructor that accepts byte arrays., so can just call your String's getBytes()